# How to install Distributed Replay (dreplay.exe) for SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, migration, sql-server-2017, distributed-replay

In SQL Server 2014, [dreplay.exe was available under "Management Tools – Basic"](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-install-configure-and-use-sql-server-distributed-replay/) feature. However, in SQL Server 2017 that feature no longer exists (Enterprise edition) and it doesn't come with SSMS installer either.
Here is what available from SQL Server 2017 installer:

[image]

Did they move dreplay.exe somewhere else?

Any help is much appreciated!

### **Update 1.**

It seems there is a bit of confusion around Distributed Replay and what exactly I am looking for. So I thought to include a diagram from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/distributed-replay/sql-server-distributed-replay?view=sql-server-ver15):

[image]

**Administration tool** (dreplay.exe) is what I am looking for.

**Controller** (DReplayController.exe) is Distributed Replay Controller from feature selection screen. It is useless without Administration tool.

**Client** (DReplayClient.exe) is Distributed Replay Client from feature selection screen. It is useless without Controller.

### **Update 2.**

OS: Windows Server 2016 Standard

SQL Server Management Studio version: 18.4 **

** (As this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1f2eae6d-71a3-4fe7-b09a-958f5c2821be/where-is-dreplayexe-in-sql-2017?forum=sqltools) suggests dreplay.exe came with SSMS 17.x, but got removed from 18.x)

SQL Server < Shared Components > version: 14.0.1000.169 ***

*** (displayed at Installation Type step or can be found in MediaInfo.xml `Property Id="BaselineVersion"` that is located in the root of disk with SQL Server installer)

Binn folder contents:

```
 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn

18/11/2019  15:19    <DIR>          .
18/11/2019  15:19    <DIR>          ..
18/11/2019  15:19    <DIR>          DQ
22/08/2017  18:39           697,528 DReplayCommon.dll
22/08/2017  18:39            20,592 DReplayServer.tlb
22/08/2017  18:40            32,952 DReplayServerPS.dll
04/11/2019  15:25    <DIR>          Resources
04/11/2019  15:28    <DIR>          schemas
15/06/2019  11:09           602,848 SqlManager.dll
22/08/2017  18:47            60,088 SQLPS.exe
22/08/2017  18:48               379 SQLPS.exe.config
15/06/2019  11:09            29,472 sqlresld.dll
15/06/2019  11:09            29,264 SqlResourceLoader.dll
15/06/2019  11:08            59,672 SQLSCM.DLL
15/06/2019  11:08           133,200 SQLSVC.DLL
              10 File(s)      1,665,995 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  97,550,450,688 bytes free
```

Comment: I see "Distributed Replay Controller" and "Distributed Replay Client" in the screen image under Shared Features. Looks like it is already installed.

Comment: @DanGuzman unfortunately, there is a 3rd thing - Distributed Replay itself (not Controller or Client), it is designed to allow to control Controller via CMD. Without Distributed Replay, you cannot use Controller

Comment: On the blogpost linked it says: "In case of adding the feature to an existing installation you will only need to check the Distributed Replay Controller and Distributed Replay Client features (only install the Client in the Controller computer if you want that server to act as client as well) otherwise select all the features that you need plus these last two related to Distributed Replay feature:". Isn't that the same as on your end?

Comment: @RandiVertongen in regard to Client and Controller - yes, it is the same! However, I am looking for 3rd thing that controls Controller. I updated my question to make this a bit clearer.

Comment: @Vladimirs thanks for the update. When installing client and controller on  SQL Server 2017 I do find `DReplay.exe` in my default location of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn`

Comment: @RandiVertongen is it definitely comes out of SQL Server installer? Maybe you have SSMS 17.x installed (i've put a link in my 2nd update where it suggests that dreplay.exe used to come with SSMS 17.x). If you do not have SSMS 17.x, would you be so kind to check your < Shared Components > version?

Comment: You are right about the 17.x, my bad! Nicely spotted.

Comment: @RandiVertongen thank you so much for taking your time and checking things for me! Shame that it only exists in SSMS 17.x that is no longer available from official websites.

Answer (score 0):

@Randi Vertongen: You really find dreplay.exe in the location you mention just by installing the DReplayClient and the DReplayController from the SQL 2017 ISO? I just installed the Controller and the Client and it is definitely not there. As mentioned in my post in the MSDN Forum  it can be installed by installing SSMS 17.x which I am going to do now - but that cannot be the solution. I have opened a Connect Item back in the days - Maybe you would like to upvote it:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38242585-where-is-dreplay-exe

Comment: Welcome to **Database administrators**. Please, notice that **answers** should be solely answers and not questions. If you have questions, you should add comments (when you have enough reputation score to do that) to ask questions that might help you answer the topic question.